# Is there a succinct way to derive a member's type during construction?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, decltype, type-deduction

I have:

- A template routine `unarchive` that takes a dictionary and a key and based on the template type (`T`) passed can be specialized to produce a `T`
- A constructor for a `struct` that leverages `unarchive` to construct its members

An example might be the following:

```
template <typename T>
T unarchive(const dictionary_t&, key_type key);

struct foo
{
    foo(const dictionary& archive) :
        value_m(unarchive<decltype(value_m)>(archive, value_key))
    { }

    some_value_type value_m;
};
```

The advantage of using `unarchive<decltype(value_m)>` here is that I can change the type of `value_m` without having to update this line of code - the type always follows the member variable's type.

The problem I have is more aesthetic: it is very verbose. Currently I have a macro:

```
#define UNARCHIVE_FOR(var) unarchive<decltype(var)>
```

And the `foo`'s constructor changes as follows:

```
foo(const dictionary& archive) :
    value_m(UNARCHIVE_FOR(value_m)(archive, value_key))
{ }
```

Now I have a result that is more terse but far uglier. Can the same result be achieved without a macro? What I would like would be something akin to:

```
foo(const dictionary& archive) :
    value_m(unarchive<value_m>(archive, value_key))
{ }
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not `unarchive(m,archive,value_key)`?

Comment: What about argument type deduction? `unarchive(value_m, archive, value_key)` - you could also provide an adapter function e.g. as static member.

Comment: I thought about that, but the variable isn't fully constructed at that point so didn't want to give off any impressions that the variable would actually be used within the routine - I wanted to pass it as a template parameter so as to reinforce that just its type was being derived.

Comment: @fbrereto In that case, `decltype` is as clear and expressive as it can get IMO.

Comment: `unarchive(&value_m,archive,value_key)` then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The advantage of using unarchive here is that I can change the type of value_m without having to update this line of code - the type always follows the member variable's type.

One alternative is to create an alias for the type of `value_m` and eliminate the `decltype(value_m)` from the constructor initializer list:

```
struct foo
{
    using value_type = int;

    foo(const dictionary_t& archive, const key_type value_key) :
        value_m(unarchive<value_type>(archive, value_key))
    { }

    value_type value_m;
};
```

the `unarchive<value_type>` still follows the type of `value_m`. A `static_assert` could be added to ensure the type of `value_m` is the same as `value_type` if there is concern of a change to the type of `value_m` by not changing `value_type`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(value_m), value_type>::value,
              "'value_m' type differs from 'value_type'");
```

or set the alias based on the type of `value_m`:

```
int value_m;
using value_type = decltype(value_m);
```

If you still consider the constructor initialization list verbose provide a `static` wrapper function that invokes the `unarchive()` function:

```
struct foo
{
    using value_type = int;

    foo(const dictionary_t& archive, const key_type value_key) :
        value_m(unarchive_(archive, value_key))
    { }

    static value_type unarchive_(const dictionary_t& d, key_type k)
    {
        return unarchive<value_type>(d, k);
    }

    value_type value_m;
};
```

Having said all that:

```
value_m(unarchive<decltype(value_m)>(archive, value_key))
```

is not that verbose and precisely states the intention.

Comment: I know it is not *that* verbose, you are right. That said the repetition of specifying the type seems sloppy and will inevitably lead to someone mismatching them down the road. I would prefer to specify the type once and be done with it. The `using` statement with the `decltype` is pretty mind blowing, too, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hackish, but how about introducing a wrapper class for the archive with a templated conversion operator:

```
class wrapper {
  const dictionary_t& dict_m;
  const key_type key_m;
public:
  wrapper(const dictionary_t& d, key_type k) :
    dict_m(d), key_m(k) {}
  template <class T> operator T () const {
    return unarchive<T>(dict_m, key_m);
  }
};
```

so you can initialize with:

```
foo(const dictionary_t& archive, const key_type value_key) :
    value_m(wrapper(archive, value_key))
{}
```

Comment: Ah, clever! I like that it makes things even more terse than before by using an implicit cast there. I'll have to muse on this idea some more, thanks.